Fail2ban bans my ip when I make an ssh connection with phpStorm
I have disbaled the ssh connection for "root" user, and When I make an ssh connection with phpStorm using my ssh credentials of the new user I have created, fail2ban bans my ip, but I can do a connection using the console !!
The ban is temporary for 1 minute, it was more 1 minute but I changed it temporary to be able to connect with ssh in the console after 1 minute of ban
[sshd]
enabled = true
port    = ssh
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
backend = %(sshd_backend)s
filter = sshd
maxretry = 3
findtime = 5m
bantime  = 1m

How can I resolve that ?

You can whitelist your IP in the fail2ban jail.local (not a good idea if your IP changes a lot).

Banning of IP addresses by fail2ban are typically temporary in nature. Did you change this configuration to make the ban permanent? Have you checked the logs for fail2ban? Is the IP still banned? Have you re-attempted an SSH connection? Please update your question with more information.

@mpboden, I have edited my question
